# Doctrine querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I build a symfony project but I have an issue with doctrine query builder.
I have two entities one named projet and the other named statutprojet and relation ManyToOne.
I want to count projects and use group by statutprojet. 

I try this and i get the result like this with a var_dump:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=1)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)
```

i want to display the result with statutprojet libelle or id

this is my code :

```
 $repo = $this   ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('BackOfficeBundle:Projet');

    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('p');
    $qb->select('COUNT(p)');
    $qb->groupBy('p.statutprojet');


    $projets = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query like this.

```
  $repo = $this ->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('BackOfficeBundle:Projet');

        $arrayCount = $repo->createQueryBuilder('p');
              ->join('p.statutprojet', 'sp')
              ->select('COUNT(p), sp.id')//or sp.name
              ->groupBy('p.statutprojet')
              ->getQuery()
              ->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: it generate the same result

Comment: @Grub_elm, did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
    $repo = $this ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('BackOfficeBundle:Projet');

    $qb= $repo->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $projects = $qb->join('p.statutprojet', 'sp')
          ->select('COUNT(p), sp.name')
          ->groupBy('sp.id')
          ->getQuery()
          ->getArrayResult();
```

And var_dump the result if it is still wrong i would like to see the result of this query and your 2 tables i would be able to help more.